# Как можно изменить тип объекта в рантайме?

Tags: c#, runtime, unsafe, void

Можно ли какими-то средствами C# изменить тип какого-то объекта на любой другой в рантайме?

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Необходимо получить поинтер на тип объекта, а затем получить поинтер на нужный вам тип и присвоить значение. Выглядеть это будет вот так (можно на самом деле переписать на generic и изменить немного `typeof`):

```
unsafe void ChangeType(byte[] arr)
{
    void** ptr = *(void***)(Unsafe.AsPointer(ref arr)); //поинтер на тип объекта arr
    *ptr = (void*)typeof(void).TypeHandle.Value; //поинтер на нужный нам тип. Вместо typeof(void) может быть typeof(ваш_тип)
}
```

Однако, у такого действия есть побочный эффект, **если** GC закинет его в **SOH**, то после Compact возможно будет изменён адрес памяти. Для LOH этого не произойдет, если явно не попросить GC дать возможность сжать LOH

Теперь, после выполнения этого метода (если смотреть в Debugger), тип будет `void`, однако это всё равно не запрещает нам итерировать и по-другому взаимодействовать с объектом как с типом который был изначально

```
var arr = new byte[] {1,2,3};
ChangeType(arr);
Console.WriteLine(byteArr.GetType());

//Вывод: System.Void
```

Comment: Это всё конечно интересно, а зачем это может понадобиться? Хотя-бы один пример рабочего использования бы узнать для какой-нибудь задачи. Допустим объект можно припинить и сделать так, чтобы GC его не собрал вообще, а дальше то что?

Comment: Кстати `*(void***)` это эквивалент `(void**)`. Можно теоретически предположить, что это типа такой низкоуровневый каст, но есть же `Unsafe.As` тогда, есть `MemoryMarshal.Cast`. А указатели вообще можно кастовать из чего угодно во что угодно вообще игнорируя типы данных.

Comment: LOH тоже можно [компактировать](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=net-7.0).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, но это можно сделать только руками как я знаю

Comment: @aepot я не знаю где это может понадобится